# DAX Ratio of missing values

Tags: powerbi, dax, percentage, missing-data

I'm trying to find a DAX formula to calculate the percent of products that are not sold in all the regions.

The table that I'm using is the Sales table which has:

- Territory
- Sales
- Product

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated column to work out if distinct Territory count match's distinct Territory count per Product

```
    All Regions = 
    VAR Territory = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sales[Territory]), All(Sales))

    VAR ProductTerritories = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sales[Territory]), ALLEXCEPT(Sales, Sales[Product]))
RETURN 
    Territory = ProductTerritories
```

This will then return True or False against each Product

[image: Product Sold in All Territories]